# Django: Mongoengine equivalent $addtoset

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

This is my `models.py`:

```
from mongoengine import *

class Venue(Document):
    location_id     =   StringField(required=True)
    name            =   StringField(required=True)
    latitude        =   FloatField(required=True)
    longitude       =   FloatField(required=True)
    address         =   StringField()
    postal_code     =   StringField()
    city            =   StringField()
    county          =   StringField()
    country_code    =   StringField()
    events          =   ListField()

    class Event(Document):
        title           =   StringField(required=True)
        description     =   StringField(required=True)
        website         =   StringField()
        start_date      =   DateTimeField(required=True)
        start_time      =   DateTimeField(required=True)
        end_date        =   DateTimeField(required=True)
        end_time        =   DateTimeField(required=True)
```

Clearly each `Venue` has many `Event`.

How can I push an `Event` model into my mongodb at the end of the list `events` of `Venue` model assuming that the target is based on the `location_id` field?

For example in pymongo I would use:

```
db.venue.update({ 'location_id': id },
        { '$addToSet' :{ 'events' : {   'title': title,
                                        'website' : website,
                                        'description' : description,
                                        'start_date' : start_date,
                                        'start_time' : start_time,
                                        'end_date' : end_date,
                                        'end_time' : end_time
                                    }   
                        }
    })
```

If you have a more optimal structure please feel free to suggest so.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a [`ReferenceField`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html?highlight=referencefield#mongoengine.fields.ReferenceField) inside a `ListField`

```
class Venue(Document):
    location_id = StringField(required=True)
    name = StringField(required=True)
    latitude = FloatField(required=True)
    longitude = FloatField(required=True)
    address = StringField()
    postal_code = StringField()
    city = StringField()
    county = StringField()
    country_code = StringField()
    events = ListField(ReferenceField('Event'), default=[])

class Event(Document):
    title = StringField(required=True)
    description = StringField(required=True)
    website = StringField()
    start_date = DateTimeField(required=True)
    start_time = DateTimeField(required=True)
    end_date = DateTimeField(required=True)
    end_time = DateTimeField(required=True)
```

and then just `Venue().events.append(Event())` shall help?

P.S. Please do not use multiple spaces around `=`